# How to remove redirect from old username to new username

Tags: support

Recently I have changed my username on all stackexchange sites but it still shows up on search engines. 
Upon clicking, stackoverflow/exchange redirects me to the new username.

Is it possible to remove the link between the old username and the new one and keep my points ?

Reason : privacy.

Regards

Comment: Shouldn't this be asked at the owners of the Search engines? This site seems to do the correct thing.

Comment: The problem is the that the "user name" is basically meaningless. What SE does is take the user id in the link, and ignore the text after it.

Comment: If you're that concerned about the amount of information you made available with your previous name then delete your account and make a new one.

Comment: Just wanted to unlink from my previous nickname, the posts are fine, I'd like to keep them. Seems like the only two options are : delete + create new user / ask an admin to change my user ID. Is that possible guys / gals ?

Answer (score 3):

You can only ask Bing to remove or refresh those entries. Looks like Google has already done so.

What you see is not so much caused by your username but by your user id. I'm not sure if creating a new account (with a new user id) and then merge this account with your new one will be of any help either. The posts you've written under your old name might still be cached by Google and for sure by the Internet Archives Wayback machine. Following  a post link brings you still on one of your posts written when you had a different name.

You can ask dissociate the posts from your account but that will have consequences for your reputation. Still clever querying in [SEDE](https://data.stackexchange.com/) might reveal your previous user name(s).

Comment: Thank you about the tip regarding SEDE. So it seems the only two options are : delete account + create new one and discard my reputation OR ask a super moderator / admin to change my user ID ? Any tips on doing that ?

Comment: @daredevil See [How can one link/merge/combine/associate two accounts/users? (Anonymous/unregistered/cookie or OpenID/registered)](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous-unregist) and [merging accounts](http://stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) which is found in the help center.